I have so many questions about this method of grounding in this video?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G8JgS-STozA&t=537s
First, I apologize this video is in a different language, but I'll point out what is relevant.
So, in this video. There is a man saying that his refrigerator gives him a shock when he touches it. So what he did to solve the issue is he takes a wire, bound one side of the wire to the metal case (via a screw), and then bond the other side to a nail, which is then nailed down the ground/wall.
@2:07, he said if you touch a plastic part, you won't get shock. But if you touch the metal, you will get shock. Ok, fair enough.
@3:33, he used a voltage test pen to show that the metal part has voltage or is energized.
@4:29, he tested again with a multimeter. He showed that there is about 113 V potential between the case and his fingers. You can see he placed the black probe on the metal part, and the red probe pinched between his fingers. I'm assuming he's BARE feet, otherwise, the multimeter will read 0 V. (Correct me if I'm wrong on this). Also, he mentioned the refrigerator is rated for 220 V (which is standard in Asia).
Here comes his solution (which I explained earlier, but I'll say it again)
@5:39, he takes a wire. You can see one side of the wire is bonded to a nail, and the nail is nailed down between the tiles (or on the ground). And for the other side of the wire, he bonds it to the metal case (via a screw). You can see @6:38
@7:34, he tested again, but this time the voltage test pen does not light up.
@8:00, he tested with the multimeter, and this time the multimeter shows about just 1 V (and not 113 V like before) between the metal case and his fingers.

WHAT THE HECK IS THIS??? Aren't you supposed to check WHY the metal case is energized???? Aren't you supposed to check WHERE the hot wire is touching the metal case, and isolate it so that the metal case won't become energized??? This solution is so unsafe!! What if the wire breaks? What if a mouse chews on it, and it breaks??? Now the metal part will become energized again! Isn't the idea of the ground wire is to trip the circuit breaker in case of a fault??? Come to think of it, why the circuit breaker did NOT trip????
So here is another question. Not so much on the safety, but on electricity. Why does the wire NOT melt?? It's taking a full 113 V across it with NO loads.

The metal cases of many devices may/will read half the main AC voltage on their metal cases if they have a 3-prong plug and require earth/ground connection but are plugged to non-earthed/ungrounded wall socket. So this part is true, just plug in a desktop PC in an old house and you have a tingly PC because it has capacitive mains filter to earth. Plus the video technique how to provide earth/ground connection may be fake just to trick people.

So you're saying if you connect a appliance to a receptacle without ground, the metal case will have voltage even though there is no ground fault?

Yes, but not all appliances, it depends on the appliance, if it has mains filter caps to earth and earth connects to metal chassis.

I didn't watch the video (don't have time) but I have measured large voltages on the external conductive surfaces of various electrical equipment many times.  It does not necessarily mean the voltage is deadly.  The usual cause is some-form of wire-less energy coupling (usually capacitive, sometimes magnetic) from internal wires to the outside case. Connecting the external metal case to earth (via a wire, or perhaps a conductive polymer) will bring this to zero with very little current flow in that wire, typically much less than 1mA.
This explains why the wire does not melt: the energy source in this case has a very high impedance, it cannot supply much current.
Yes, it is always best that conductive surfaces are tied to ground, but the wiring rules do permit this provided that the insulation system is sufficiently safe.  What is deemed to be "sufficiently safe" is set by the electrical wiring rules (AS3000 in Australia) & varies from country to country.

oh... I didn't know about capacitive coupling or magnetic coupling. So it seems the refrigerator outer case isn't caused by coming in direct contact with a live wire.

Correct.  If that was the case, then that would indeed be capable of delivering a lethal shock.

@NhitC At least in my country metal cases need to be wired internally to the protective ground of the 3-wire mains. And so this situation should not exist. Should, as errors happen, and you are right to ask for checking why there is voltage in the first place.

@the busybee, the man in the video is Vietnamese. If i'm not mistaken, many appliances in Vietnam use only 2-prongs. Most wall receptacles only have a hot and a neutral but no ground. They probably depend heavily on GFCI for protection. But this still doesn't explain why it didn't trip the circuit when the wire is bonded to ground. So the possible explanation by the commenter is the case is energized due to capacitive or magnetic coupling.
